# Как передать значение переменной в класс, находящийся в другом файле?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qgraphicsscene

Есть проект, в котором есть `QGraphicsView`, в нем происходит либо отрисовка прямоугольника, либо линии. 
Выбор между ними осуществляется по средствам `QRadioButton`.

Изначально все было в одном файле и худо-бедно работало, но появилась необходимость вынести класс работы с `QGraphicsView` в отдельный файл.

Проблема заключается в том, что отслеживание нажатия на `QRadioButton` происходит в файле **main.py**, а результат должен быть передан в **GraphicsScene.py**. 
Обратиться через объект в другом файле я не могу, так как он выдает ошибку и программа завершается.

Мне нужно получить результат выполнения функции для отслеживания нажатия.
Я зашел в тупик. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Код проекта:

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from cmapSelector import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

from GraphicsScene import GraphicsScene
from coordCatch import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore



class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__()
        
        self.counter = 0
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.resize(840, 740) 

        self.gscene = GraphicsScene()        
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.gscene)
        self.graphicsView.show()
        self.graphicsView.setFixedSize(710, 610)

        self.pixmap = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(self.pixmap) 

        global ruler
        ruler = False

#---------------------- Создает виджет QGridLayout -----------------------------
        self.sublayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.sublayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.sublayout, 0, 2)

        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 0)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 4)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self._rul_rect_)

    def _rul_rect_(self):
        global ruler
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            ruler = True
        else:
            ruler = False  



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 

    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show() 
    app.exec_()  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    main()
```

**GraphicsScene.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, Qt



class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)

        global ruler
        ruler = True # сделано что бы пример работал (если присвоить False, выведет прямоугольник)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self._pos = QPointF()
        self._current_item = None
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.startPos = QPointF()
        self.finPose = QPointF()
        self.rulerItem = None
        self.textItem = None
        self.lineItem = None    
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        self.xpos = None
        self.ypos = None
        self.selecting = False
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,1063,1418)
        self.selection = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle)
        self.addWidget(self.selection)
        self.originQPoint = None
        self.originCropPoint = None
        self.currentQRect = None


        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.selecting = True
        self.originQPoint = event.scenePos()
        self.selection.hide()
        self.originCropPoint = event.scenePos()
        
        if ruler != True:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
            self.removeItem(self.lineItem)
            self.removeItem(self.textItem)
            self.lineItem = None
            self.textItem = None
            self._pos = event.scenePos()
            self._current_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
            self._current_item.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff0000'), 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
            self.addItem(self._current_item)
            self._current_item.setRect(QRectF(self._pos, self._pos))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        else:
            self.startPos = event.scenePos().toPoint()
            self.rulerItem = QGraphicsLineItem()
            self.rulerItem.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff00aa'), 3))
            self.addItem(self.rulerItem)
            self.rulerItem.setLine(QLineF(self.startPos, self.startPos))

            self.coordinates = QLineF(self.startPos, self.startPos)
            self.letter = 'С.П. = ' + str(int(self.coordinates.length()))
            if self.textItem == None:
                self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(self.startPos)
                self.textItem.setBrush(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.textItem.setPen(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.addItem(self.textItem)
            else:
                self.removeItem(self.textItem)
                self.removeItem(self.lineItem)
                self.lineItem = None
                self.textItem = None

                self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(self.startPos)
                self.textItem.setBrush(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.textItem.setPen(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.addItem(self.textItem)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.clicked.emit()

    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.originQPoint is not None and self.selecting:
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint.toPoint(), 
                                event.scenePos().toPoint())
            self.selection.setGeometry(rect)
            self.selection.show()

        if ruler != True:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if self._current_item:
                rect = QRectF(self._pos, event.scenePos()).normalized()
                self._current_item.setRect(rect)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        else:
            if self.rulerItem:
                self.coordinates = QLineF(self.startPos, event.scenePos())
                self.rulerItem.setLine(QLineF(self.coordinates))
                
                self.letter = 'С.П. = ' + str(int(self.coordinates.length()))
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(event.scenePos())
                self.removeItem(self.textItem)
                self.addItem(self.textItem)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        global letter
        self.selecting = False
        self.selection.hide()
        self.currentQRect = QtCore.QRect(self.originCropPoint.toPoint(), 
                                         event.scenePos().toPoint())
        print(self.currentQRect)

        if ruler != True:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            self.removeItem(self._current_item)
            self._current_item = None
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        else:
            self.finPose = event.scenePos().toPoint()
            self.removeItem(self.rulerItem)    
            self.rulerItem = None  

            self.lineItem = QGraphicsLineItem()
            self.addItem(self.lineItem)
            self.lineItem.setLine(QLineF(self.startPos, self.finPose))
            self.lineItem.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff00aa'), 3)) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**coordCatch.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(642, 491)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 441, 331))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 50, 171, 141))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Линейка"))
```

На всякий случай скрины с примером работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файлы .py в Питоне - это модули. Поэтому связать их можно с помощью импорта. Вы пробовали в файле, куда вам нужно передать результат, импортировать другой файл, в котором этот результат определяется?

Comment: Например, если файлы в одной папке, то в main.py пишете ```import coordCatch``` И тогда сможете в нём обращаться к переменным и функциям файла coordCatch. ```coordCatch.переменная```

Comment: @Tester нет, ваше предложение не для данного случая. Я попробую ответить на этот вопрос чуть позже.

Comment: @Tester, да, я пробовал обращаться через импорт, программа выдает ошибку: `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании экземпляра класса `GraphicsScene()`, 
передайте ссылку на объект класса `ExampleApp()`:

```
# !!! --------------------> vvvv <------- +++ self !!!
self.gscene = GraphicsScene(self)
```

В классе `GraphicsScene()`:

```
class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)

# !! -> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------      +++       
        self.parent = parent
```

Далее в классе `GraphicsScene()`:

вместо `ruler`:
#-        if ruler != True:

используйте `self.parent.radioButton.isChecked()`:

```
    if not self.parent.radioButton.isChecked():
```

Помните, не рекомендуется злоупотреблять глобальными переменными,
как указано в разделе [**Почему глобальные переменные - зло?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ??? from matplotlib.pyplot import *

from q1456272_GraphicsScene import GraphicsScene
from q1456272_coordCatch import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
# ???    self.counter = 0
#        self.resize(840, 740) 
        self.resize(640, 480) 


        print(f'class ExampleApp:    self   = {self}') 
# !!! ----------------------------> vvvv <--------------------------- +++ self !!!
        self.gscene = GraphicsScene(self)  
        
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.gscene)
        self.graphicsView.show()
# ?      self.graphicsView.setFixedSize(710, 610)

        self.pixmap = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.graphicsView.scene().addItem(self.pixmap) 
#        self.pixmap.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('im.png'))
        
#--
# ???         global ruler
# ???         ruler = False

        # Создает виджет QGridLayout 
# ???    self.sublayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
# ???    self.sublayout.addWidget(self.radioButton)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0)
# ???    self.layout.addLayout(self.sublayout, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0, 1)                        # +++

# ???        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 0)
# ???        self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 0)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 4)

        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self._rul_rect_)                    # ???

    def _rul_rect_(self):                                                    # ??? 
        print(f'{self.radioButton.isChecked()}') #
# ???         global ruler
# ???         if self.radioButton.isChecked():
# ???             ruler = True
# ???         else:
# ???             ruler = False  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1456272_GraphicsScene.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ??? from matplotlib.pyplot import *


class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
# ???    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)

# !! -> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------------------------      +++       
        self.parent = parent
        print(f'class GraphicsScene: parent = {parent} --- '
              f'radioButton.isChecked() = {self.parent.radioButton.isChecked()}') 

# ???         global ruler
# ???         ruler = True # сделано что бы пример работал (если присвоить False, выведет прямоугольник)

        self._pos = QPointF()
        self._current_item = None

        self.startPos = QPointF()
        self.finPose = QPointF()
        self.rulerItem = None
        self.textItem = None
        self.lineItem = None    
        
        self.xpos = None
        self.ypos = None
        self.selecting = False
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1063, 1418)
        self.selection = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle)
        self.addWidget(self.selection)
        self.originQPoint = None
        self.originCropPoint = None
        self.currentQRect = None
       
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.selecting = True
        self.originQPoint = event.scenePos()
        self.selection.hide()
        self.originCropPoint = event.scenePos()
       
#-        if ruler != True:
# +++
        if not self.parent.radioButton.isChecked():                                  # +++ 
            if self.lineItem is None or self.textItem is None:                                                # +++ 
                pass
            else:
                self.removeItem(self.lineItem)
                self.removeItem(self.textItem)
                self.lineItem = None
                self.textItem = None
            
            self._pos = event.scenePos()
            self._current_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
            self._current_item.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff0000'), 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
            self.addItem(self._current_item)
            self._current_item.setRect(QRectF(self._pos, self._pos))
        else:
            self.startPos = event.scenePos().toPoint()
            self.rulerItem = QGraphicsLineItem()
            self.rulerItem.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff00aa'), 3))
            self.addItem(self.rulerItem)
            self.rulerItem.setLine(QLineF(self.startPos, self.startPos))

# ???            self.coordinates = QLineF(self.startPos, self.startPos)
# ???            self.letter = 'С.П. = ' + str(int(self.coordinates.length()))      
            self.letter = f'С.П. = {event.scenePos().x()}, {event.scenePos().y()}'  # +++

# ???            if self.textItem == None:
            if self.textItem is None:
                self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(self.startPos)
                self.textItem.setBrush(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.textItem.setPen(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.addItem(self.textItem)
            else:
                self.removeItem(self.textItem)
                self.removeItem(self.lineItem)
                self.lineItem = None
                self.textItem = None

                self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(self.startPos)
                self.textItem.setBrush(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.textItem.setPen(QColor('#ff0000'))
                self.addItem(self.textItem)
# ???        self.clicked.emit()
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.originQPoint is not None and self.selecting:
            rect = QtCore.QRect(self.originQPoint.toPoint(), 
                                event.scenePos().toPoint())
            self.selection.setGeometry(rect)
            self.selection.show()

#-        if ruler != True:
        if not self.parent.radioButton.isChecked():
            if self._current_item:
                rect = QRectF(self._pos, event.scenePos()).normalized()
                self._current_item.setRect(rect)
        else:
            if self.rulerItem:
# ???                self.coordinates = QLineF(self.startPos, event.scenePos())
# ???                self.rulerItem.setLine(QLineF(self.coordinates))
# ???                self.letter = 'С.П. = ' + str(int(self.coordinates.length()))
                self.letter = f'x = {event.scenePos().x()}, y = {event.scenePos().y()}' # +++              
                
                self.textItem.setText(self.letter)
                self.textItem.setPos(event.scenePos())
                self.removeItem(self.textItem)
                self.addItem(self.textItem)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
# ???        global letter
        self.selecting = False
        self.selection.hide()
        self.currentQRect = QtCore.QRect(self.originCropPoint.toPoint(), 
                                         event.scenePos().toPoint())
        print(f'def mouseReleaseEvent(): self.currentQRect = {self.currentQRect}')

#-        if ruler != True:
        if not self.parent.radioButton.isChecked():
            self.removeItem(self._current_item)
            self._current_item = None
        else:
            self.finPose = event.scenePos().toPoint()
            self.removeItem(self.rulerItem)    
            self.rulerItem = None  

            self.lineItem = QGraphicsLineItem()
            self.addItem(self.lineItem)
            self.lineItem.setLine(QLineF(self.startPos, self.finPose))
            self.lineItem.setPen(QPen(QColor('#ff00aa'), 3))
```

**q1456272_coordCatch.py**  - это ваш модуль **coordCatch.py**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Эти ссылки будут полезны для вас:

- [Зачем нужно использовать графическую сцену QGraphicsScene?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1391976/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-qgraphicsscene/1392002#1392002)
- [В чём разница между сценой и представлением в PyQt5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110849/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-pyqt5/1111074#1111074)
- [Почему не работает считывание координаты при нажатии мышкой по scene?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200469/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-scene/1200553#1200553)
- [События пользовательского QGraphicsRectItem в PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950081/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-qgraphicsrectitem-%D0%B2-pyqt5/950195#950195)

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало как должно, и спасибо за предложенную литературу.

Comment: @MikhailBorisov пожалуйста.